# Visual Studio 2005 (and other) : how to deploy debug dll (msvcp80p.dll & friends, for debugging purposes)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005, side-by-side

I am trying to run (and debug) my application on a remote computer where Visual Studio 2005 is not installed.
My current problem is that I am facing the (in)famous error : "The application failed to start because the application configuration  is incorrect".

Here is what I did :

1) Install all the required vcredist on the target computer :
(I do need all theses versions since some libraries were compiled some months ago, with a previous runtime...).

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5638)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14431)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347)

After installing those redist, the release version works fine.

2) Install the debug dll following the  instructions given on the following MSDN pages: [Preparing a Test Machine To Run a Debug Executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)   and at [How to: Deploy using XCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**As mentioned in "Preparing a Test Machine To Run a Debug Executable":**

- I did run "msiexec /i microsoft_vc80_debugcrt_x86.msm" --> This did not solve the problem.
- After that, I added "msiexec /i policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_DebugMFC_x86.msm" --> No luck either.
- As a last resort, I did "msiexec /i" for all the msm that are in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules\*VC80*.msm  --> No luck either

**As mentionned is "Deploy using XCopy":**

I also copied (in subfolders) all the subfolders of

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\redist\x86\

and

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\

to my app dir on the target machine. 
The problem is still present.

Does anyone know what I might be missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer my own question : the easiest way is to add a "Setup and deployment project" to the solution.

- Right click solution / Add new project : Other Project types / Setup and deployment
- Right click the new deployment project and select "Add/Project Output" then select your target project
  --> this will create a msi that will install all required debug dll !

(Once installed by the msi, the debug dlls are deployed once and for all : you will not need to reinstall them using an msi each time you want to test a new build).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool to find what DLL(s) you missed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but Dependency walker will not help. It keeps saying that msvcp80d.dll is missing, whenever I try to install with the options explained in my questions